# Consulta SQL para campos Chave estrangeira null

Tags: sql

Tenho uma relação que possui a tabela:

```
maoObra
(
        id*
    ,   descricao
    ,   valor
    ,   ...
)
```

E a tabela:

```
pecas
(
        id*
    ,   nome
    ,   valor
    ,   ...
)
```

Tenho uma outra tabela:

```
ItensServico
(
        id*
    ,   data
    ,   pecas_id
    ,   maoObra_id
    ,   ...
)
```

Onde os atributos `peca_id` e `maoObra_id` são chaves estrangeiras fracas na tabela de `ItensServico`.

Na tabela `ItensServico` posso receber uma tupla que, ou é da tabela `pecas` ou da tabela `maoObra` e nunca das duas, ou seja, quando em uma tupla eu inserir o atributo `peca_id`, o atributo `maoObra_id` será `null` e o inverso também é verdadeiro.

Eu preciso de uma consulta que retorne a tupla, mas que retorne os atributos de uma tabela quando seu campo chave estrangeira NÃO for nulo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talvez assim consiga resolver o seu problema:

```
SELECT      ISE.id
        ,   ISE.data
        ,   Id          = ISNULL(MO.id, PE.id)
        ,   Descricao   = (CASE WHEN MO.id IS NOT NULL THEN MO.descricao    ELSE PE.nome    END)
        ,   Valor       = (CASE WHEN MO.id IS NOT NULL THEN MO.valor        ELSE PE.valor   END)
FROM        ItensServico    ISE
LEFT JOIN   maoObra         MO  ON MO.id = ISE.maoObra_id
LEFT JOIN   pecas           PE  ON PE.id = ISE.pecas_id
```

Comment: Obrigado João, era isso que precisava.